# Prove that $\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R},(x,y) \rightarrow y-x$ is measurable

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ a measurable application. I have to prove that $Gr(f) = \{(x,f(x)) : x \in \mathbb{R}\}$ is measurable.

For it, I have to prove that $\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R},(x,y) \rightarrow y-x$ is measurable and $\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2,(x,y) \rightarrow (f(x),y)$ is measurable also.

I don't see how to prove that $\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R},(x,y) \rightarrow y-x$ is measurable. Actually, if $h(x,y)=y-x$ and $B \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$, I want to show that $h^{-1}(B) \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R^2})$. To do it, I need to know $h^{-1}$ but I don't see at all how to obtain it... Could someone help me ? Thank you in advance !

Comment: What is measurable application?

Comment: I don't know the English translation. "Measurable function"...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The map $\varphi:{\bf{R}}^{2}\rightarrow{\bf{R}}$, $\varphi(x,y)=y-x$ is continuous and hence Borel measurable.